# accessing *args from within a function in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments, args

Hi everyone this is probably something extremely simple that i'm overlooking but can someone point me in the right direction for how to handle this problem.

```
def nodeFunction(self,*args):
    return self[1] + self[2]
```

Basically what I am trying to do is grab the data passed in through the arguments. I am just stuck on the syntax for referencing the arguments inside the function when using `*args`.

Comment: A neat rule of thumb in Python is that names have to come from somewhere; they don't get magically inserted by the language. (An instance method refers to the instance as `self` only because that is the first argument to the method -- there's no magic `this`. A setter for a property refers to the value it is setting as an argument -- there's no magic `value`. If you want to use a function inside a module `foo`, you have to import `foo` so that the interpreter knows what it is. Etc.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`args` is simply a tuple:

```
def nodeMethod(self, *args):
    return args[0], args[1]
```

Is that what you mean?

Note that there's nothing special about "args". You could use any variable name. It's the `*` operator that counts.

```
>>> class Node(object):
...     def nodeMethod(self, *cornucopia):
...         return cornucopia[0], cornucopia[1]
... 
>>> n = Node()
>>> n.nodeMethod(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2)
```

Still, "args" is the most idiomatic variable name; I wouldn't use anything else without a good reason that would be obvious to others.

Comment: Bloody hell, I am such an idiot, sorry im still getting the hang of python. Thats exactly what I was looking for thank you. Ill accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 5):

```
def nodeFunction(self, arg1, arg2, *args)
```

`*arg` in argument list means: pass the remaning arguments as a list in variable `arg`. So check how to handle [list](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html)s. Note: list index starts from `0`.